# VPN split tunnel force specific domains to go to VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, dns, tunnel

I have a VPN server that I am connecting to on Windows 10 (pretend it is Win8) via a split tunnel. There are some domains, let's call them a.vpndomain.com and b.vpndomain.com, that I want to connect through the VPN server, not my local internet (the VPN does not have working outbound internet, so that is why I am doing split tunnel). However, a.vpndomain.com and b.vpndomain.com are both websites on the internet. Windows seems to be routing these domains to the internet, rather than to the VPN server. However, typing the local IP for these domains works as expected, though it is inconvenient. Is there some way to force these domains to route to the VPN when I am connected?

By the way, sorry if this belongs in Server Fault. If it does, please notify me and I will move it. I figured it was dealing with my local configuration rather than the VPN as this works fine on Linux, just not on Windows.

Comment: Do a.vpndomain.com and b.vpndomain.com resolve to public IP addresses (i.e. not LAN addresses) ?

Comment: If you use a normal dns (say 8.8.8.8), yes. However, the dns in the vpn server maps it to a local ip, which is what i want for those.